# Unity VR autoclick after few seconds

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

I am using the GoogleVR package and I have this reticle which works (in the sense that it makes an object I am looking at bigger). The behavior I would like, is to click by looking on object for about three seconds. The object currently has an event trigger, but how can I wait for three seconds and then click?

Answer (score 0):

When you look at the object, the trigger is activated right?
Then when you detect the trigger up just make a function that waits for 3 seconds and and then do what you want.

Dont forget to stop the wait if the user starts looking somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this script a while ago, it works fine with buttons:

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(Button))]
public class InteractiveItem : MonoBehaviour, IPointerEnterHandler, IPointerExitHandler, IPointerClickHandler   
{
    public Image progressImage;  // add an image as child of button and set its image type to Filled. And assign it here.
    public bool isEntered = false;

    float GazeActivationTime = 3f;
    float timeElapsed;
    Button _button;

    void Start () 
    {
        _button = GetComponent<Button>();
    }

    void fillProgress(float value)
    {
        if (progressImage != null)
        {
            progressImage.fillAmount = value;
        }
    }

    void Update () 
    {
        if(isEntered)
        {
            timeElapsed += Time.deltaTime;
            fillProgress(Mathf.Clamp(timeElapsed/GazeActivationTime,0,1));
            if(timeElapsed >= GazeActivationTime)
            {
                timeElapsed = 0;
                _button.onClick.Invoke();
                fillProgress(0);
                isEntered = false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            timeElapsed = 0;
        }
    }

    void OnDisable()
    {
        if (this.enabled)
        {
            isEntered = false;
            fillProgress(0);    
        }
    }

#region IPointerEnterHandler implementation

    public void OnPointerEnter (PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        if (_button.IsInteractable())
        {
            isEntered = true;
        }
    }

#endregion

#region IPointerExitHandler implementation

    public void OnPointerExit (PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        if (!_button.IsInteractable())
            return;
        try
        {
            isEntered = false;
            fillProgress(0);
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.LogError(ex.Message);
        }
    }
#endregion

#region IPointerClickHandler implementation

    public void OnPointerClick (PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        isEntered = false;
        timeElapsed = 0;
        fillProgress(0);

    }
#endregion

}
```